# Change binding depending of value of list item property in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I have the following xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="SomeClass_SomeListProperty">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}"/> <!--This is a string-->
                    <TextBlock Text=": "/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}"/> <!--This is a long-->
                </WrapPanel>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Stretch="None"
                      Source="{Binding BoolThatDependsOnType, 
                      Converter={StaticResource BoolToImageConverter}, 
                      ConverterParameter='large'}" />
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Settings"
                      cal:Message.Attach="MethodCallThatDependsOnType"/>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Can I somehow bind the bool "BoolThatDependsOnType" depending on the value of Type? The problem I'm having is that the image source is set depending on if a certain bool is true or false. I want to select which bool to bind to depending on if Type is "type1", "type2" or "type3" for the particular list item.

Comment: Use a MultiBinding with an appropriate multi-binding converter.

Comment: Don't know how I've missed this, looks like the right thing for me, will try it out! @Clemens

Comment: I don't think this will quite work unless I am missing something. If Type is "type1" I need the Image Source to bind to the bool property IsType1Ok in the view model (which is then converted to a bitmap). Is this even possible? @Clemens

Comment: In the MultiBinding you would bind to Type and all the boolean properties, and in the converter you would select the appropriate boolean value depending on the value of Type.

Comment: All right, I was going to try that but it felt like a bad solution to include all properties "just in case". Guess i'm lucky there's only 3 of them in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With inspiration from @Clemens I came to the following solution using a `IMultiValueConverter` and `MultiBinding` (and no the variable and method names are not the actual ones used :-) ).

```
public class TypeAndMultipleBoolsToImageConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values == null) return new BitmapImage(new Uri("some/path.png", UriKind.Relative));
            bool isOk;
            switch (((string) values[0]).ToLower(culture))
            {
                case "type1":
                    isOk = (bool) values[1];
                    break;
                case "type2":
                    isOk = (bool) values[2];
                    break;
                case "type3":
                    isOk = (bool) values[3];
                    break;
                default:
                    return new BitmapImage(new Uri("/some/path.png", UriKind.Relative));
            }
            return ConvertBoolToImage(isOk);
        }

        private static BitmapImage ConvertBoolToImage(bool isOk)
        {
            return isOk
                ? new BitmapImage(new Uri("/some/ok/path.png", UriKind.Relative))
                : new BitmapImage(new Uri("/some/not/ok/path.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

---

```
<Image Stretch="None">
    <Image.Source>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TypeAndMultipleBoolsToImageConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Type"/>
            <Binding Path="DataContext.IsType1Ok"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
            <Binding Path="DataContext.IsType2Ok"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
            <Binding Path="DataContext.IsType3Ok"
                     RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```